# XSLT 2.0; better solution than xsl:choose inside xsl:function to adress different date formats?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to improve XSLT code that I wrote a while ago. I have a function that converts a date into the XSLT format.

I have two cases:

- the date is in German format (e.g., 10.05.2014)
- the date is in a different format

Currently I am solving this by using `xsl:choose` inside the function. When the date contains a dot, do this, otherwise do that.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? My way seems a little hacky to me. Could I use some sort of function overloading here?

**CODE**

```
<xsl:function name="ab:convDate">

    <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($date,'.')">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$date" regex="([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:variable name="month" select="number(regex-group(2))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="day" select="number(regex-group(1))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="year" select="number(regex-group(3))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="hours" select="number(regex-group(4))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="number(regex-group(5))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="dateTime" select="xs:dateTime( 
                                            concat($year, '-', 
                                            format-number($month, '00'), '-', 
                                            format-number($day, '00'), 'T', 
                                            format-number($hours, '00'), ':', 
                                            format-number($minutes, '00'), ':00Z')  
                                )"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dateTime"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$date" regex="([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:variable name="year" select="number(regex-group(1))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="month" select="number(regex-group(2))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="day" select="number(regex-group(3))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="hours" select="number(regex-group(4))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="number(regex-group(5))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="number(regex-group(6))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="dateTime" select="xs:dateTime( 
                                            concat($year, '-', 
                                            format-number($month, '00'), '-', 
                                            format-number($day, '00'), 'T', 
                                            format-number($hours, '00'), ':', 
                                            format-number($minutes, '00'), ':', 
                                            format-number($seconds, '00'),'Z')  
                                )"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dateTime"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>

        </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:function>
```

**USAGE**

```
<file date="{ab:convDate(current-group()[7])}"
</file>
```

applied to this element:

```
<el>2014-02-13 13:42:23</el>
```

or

```
<el>13.02.2014 13:42:23</el>
```

So `current-group()[7]` equals one of the two date strings.

Comment: Can you post your function and maybe an example or two of usage?

Comment: Well for that second format `<el>2014-02-13 13:42:23</el>` it would suffice to use `xs:dateTime(translate($date, ' ', 'T'))`. Also note that your function creates an `xs:dateTime` in a variable but then uses `xsl:value-of` with that variable which returns a text node containing the dateTime value, if your function is supposed to return an `xs:dateTime` you should use `<xsl:sequence select="$dateTime"/>` instead of the value-of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nicer solution might be to define two template rules matching the two formats:

```
<xsl:template match="a[contains(., '.')]">
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="a[contains(., '-')]">
```

But it's really a matter of individual preference.